# Pandas Groupby 24-hour periods regardless of date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How can I perform a pandas groupby on a dataframe in 24-hour blocks, ignoring the date of the timestamp? I've tried with `pandas.Grouper` with the `freq` argument set to `24H`. However, it stubbornly groups by the date of the timestamp. I want it to group every 24 hours beginning at the hour of the first timestamp. For example, if it starts at hour 17, I want it to group up to hour 16 of the following day and continue the groups like this through the dataframe. How can I get a grouper to ignore the date?

Here is an example of what I get:

```
df_groupby = df_tmp.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='24H'))
for idx, (_, group_df) in enumerate(df_groupby):
    print(f"Group {idx}:")
    print(group_df[['created_at', 'moisture']])
    print('-------------------')
```

Output:

```
Group 0:
                   created_at  moisture
0  2023-11-18 12:13:12.256927       535
1  2023-11-18 13:13:20.147592       535
2  2023-11-18 14:13:27.097894       535
3  2023-11-18 15:13:25.985715       535
4  2023-11-18 16:13:32.408867       534
5  2023-11-18 17:13:36.298025       534
6  2023-11-18 18:13:43.110883       534
7  2023-11-18 19:13:43.369302       534
8  2023-11-18 20:13:51.632185       534
9  2023-11-18 21:13:59.169360       534
10 2023-11-18 22:14:07.972644       534
11 2023-11-18 23:14:16.297836       533
-------------------
Group 1:
                   created_at  moisture
12 2023-11-19 00:14:26.031192       534
13 2023-11-19 01:14:39.796824       532
14 2023-11-19 02:14:44.249399       533
15 2023-11-19 03:14:53.479820       534
16 2023-11-19 04:14:55.977077       534
17 2023-11-19 05:15:07.361019       534
18 2023-11-19 06:15:11.359716       534
19 2023-11-19 07:15:18.545638       534
20 2023-11-19 08:15:21.923445       534
21 2023-11-19 09:15:44.108795       534
22 2023-11-19 10:15:57.429115       533
23 2023-11-19 11:16:06.081096       534
24 2023-11-19 12:16:13.537274       534
25 2023-11-19 13:16:20.113579       534
26 2023-11-19 14:16:27.592455       534
27 2023-11-19 15:16:40.897159       533
28 2023-11-19 16:16:46.088631       534
29 2023-11-19 17:16:56.356958       533
30 2023-11-19 18:17:07.224618       534
31 2023-11-19 19:17:16.432370       533
32 2023-11-19 20:17:26.111768       533
33 2023-11-19 21:17:34.791802       533
34 2023-11-19 22:17:43.986497       531
35 2023-11-19 23:17:52.805056       532
-------------------
Group 2:
                   created_at  moisture
36 2023-11-20 00:17:54.619490       533
37 2023-11-20 01:18:01.641144       532
38 2023-11-20 02:18:04.765892       532
39 2023-11-20 03:18:12.408328       532
40 2023-11-20 04:18:19.164817       532
41 2023-11-20 05:18:25.246881       532
42 2023-11-20 06:18:30.721551       532
43 2023-11-20 07:18:37.083176       532
44 2023-11-20 08:18:50.404909       532
45 2023-11-20 09:18:57.631082       532
46 2023-11-20 10:19:16.824349       532
47 2023-11-20 11:19:33.221346       532
48 2023-11-20 12:19:42.545535       532
49 2023-11-20 13:19:49.395201       532
50 2023-11-20 14:19:57.886827       532
51 2023-11-20 15:20:06.339089       532
52 2023-11-20 16:20:10.990417       532
53 2023-11-20 17:20:17.104666       532
54 2023-11-20 18:20:22.420334       532
55 2023-11-20 19:20:23.556865       533
56 2023-11-20 20:20:31.798930       531
57 2023-11-20 21:20:35.866586       531
58 2023-11-20 22:20:45.136861       531
59 2023-11-20 23:20:55.456402       531
-------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `origin` parameter of [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
# origin='start_day' (default)
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='24H')).size()
created_at
2023-12-01     7  # from 2023-12-01 17:00:00 to 2023-12-01 23:00:00
2023-12-02    18
Freq: 24H, dtype: int64

# origin='start' (what you expect)
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='24H', origin='start')).size()
created_at
2023-12-01 17:00:00    24  # from 2023-12-01 17:00:00 to 2023-12-02 16:00:00
2023-12-02 17:00:00     1
Freq: 24H, dtype: int64

# same with resample
>>> df.resample(rule='24H', on='created_at', origin='start').size()
created_at
2023-12-01 17:00:00    24
2023-12-02 17:00:00     1
Freq: 24H, dtype: int64
```

Minimal Working Example

```
dti = pd.date_range('2023-12-01 17:00', '2023-12-02 17:00', freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at': dti , 'moisture': 1})
print(df)

# Output
            created_at  moisture
0  2023-12-01 17:00:00         1
1  2023-12-01 18:00:00         1
2  2023-12-01 19:00:00         1
3  2023-12-01 20:00:00         1
4  2023-12-01 21:00:00         1
5  2023-12-01 22:00:00         1
6  2023-12-01 23:00:00         1  # <- end when origin='start_day'
7  2023-12-02 00:00:00         1
8  2023-12-02 01:00:00         1
9  2023-12-02 02:00:00         1
10 2023-12-02 03:00:00         1
11 2023-12-02 04:00:00         1
12 2023-12-02 05:00:00         1
13 2023-12-02 06:00:00         1
14 2023-12-02 07:00:00         1
15 2023-12-02 08:00:00         1
16 2023-12-02 09:00:00         1
17 2023-12-02 10:00:00         1
18 2023-12-02 11:00:00         1
19 2023-12-02 12:00:00         1
20 2023-12-02 13:00:00         1
21 2023-12-02 14:00:00         1
22 2023-12-02 15:00:00         1
23 2023-12-02 16:00:00         1  # <- end when origin='start'
24 2023-12-02 17:00:00         1
```